# Перерисовка JPanel

Tags: java, swing, сортировка, graphics, jpanel

Добрый день! Возникла проблема... Не получаеться перерисовать содержимое панели, которая является вкладкой в tabbedPane. Если во время процесса сортиоовки переключиться на другую вкладку, а потом снова вернуться к данной сортировке, то содержимое панели перерисовывается.

Работа на тему визуализации процесса сортировки.

```
public class Bubble_sort_panel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

Thread thread;
boolean now_sort = false;

public Bubble_sort_panel() {
}

public void bubble_sort() throws InterruptedException {
    now_sort = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    for (int i = 0; i < Constant.getN(); i++) {               // активные прямоугольники выделить другим цветом
        if (i == Variable.getIndex_of_spaw_element_bubble() || i == Variable.getIndex_of_spaw_element_bubble()+1) {
            g2.setColor(Constant.getColorOfActyveRectangle());
            g2.fill(rectangle_array_for_bubble[i]);
        }
        else {
            g2.setColor(Constant.getColorOfRectangle());
            g2.fill(rectangle_array_for_bubble[i]);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (now_sort) {
        try {

            for (int i = array_for_bubble.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    if (array_for_bubble[j] > array_for_bubble[j + 1]) {
                        Variable.setIndex_of_spaw_element_bubble(j);

                        /*

                             // вызвать перерисовку

                         */

                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                        int t = array_for_bubble[j];
                        double posX = rectangle_array_for_bubble[j].getX();

                        array_for_bubble[j] = array_for_bubble[j + 1];
                        rectangle_array_for_bubble[j].setFrame(rectangle_array_for_bubble[j+1].getX() , rectangle_array_for_bubble[j].getY(), rectangle_array_for_bubble[j].getWidth() , rectangle_array_for_bubble[j].getHeight());

                        array_for_bubble[j + 1] = t;
                        rectangle_array_for_bubble[j+1].setFrame(posX, rectangle_array_for_bubble[j+1].getY(), rectangle_array_for_bubble[j+1].getWidth(), rectangle_array_for_bubble[j+1].getHeight());

                        Rectangle2D r = rectangle_array_for_bubble[j];
                        rectangle_array_for_bubble[j] = rectangle_array_for_bubble[j + 1];
                        rectangle_array_for_bubble[j + 1] = r;
                    }
                }
            }

            now_sort = false;

        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (!now_sort) {
        thread.interrupt();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: rectangle_array_for_bubble почему не синхронизирован? Вы его в отдельном потоке как я понимаю заполняете, а в UI берете данные из него.

Answer (score 0):

Могу ошибаться, но должен помочь обычный `repaint()`.

Comment: а перед repaint() сделайте еще и revalidate